# Printing a dataframe from a function nicely as in Jupyter

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, printing, jupyter-notebook

I've seen a lot of very helpful posts on using prettyprint and such; they have been very helpful -- thanks.

What I'm wondering if there is anyway to print a dataframe from a function and have it output as "prettily" as Jupyter notebook does:

[image: Jupyter notebook display]

My main reason is I would like to use pandas's styling functions to highlight/shade.  I also want to print from a function and not a Jupyter code box if possible as I have some packages I have created and I may want to spit out 2 or more dataframes in a call.

Using prettyprint or print() alone gives a purely text output:

```
>       Year      Month  Mean Maximum Temperature Albury  \ 
> 672   1955    January                             30.8    
> 673   1955   February                             27.9    
> 674   1955      March                             26.7
> 675   1955      April                             22.1  
> ....
```

I'd like the graphical output.  Not using print(), e.g.

```
historic_dataframe
```

does nothing if within a function.

My thanks for your time.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `display` from `IPython` instead of print

```
import pandas as pd
from IPython.display import display

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.random((10, 10)))
display(df)
```

[display docs](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display)

Comment: Thank you, Dan G; that is great!  And sorry for not finding the earlier question and asking a duplicate.

Comment: The classical case. I clicked on upvote, since I have not seen that it was marked as duplicate...