# Pretty print of R Jupyter Notebook inside a function

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-irkernel

When calling `head(...)` in a cell in jupyter notebook, we get a nice table with the data

[image]

However if I want to do the same in a function, nothing is shown, so I have to use `print(head(...))` but the result is less pretty as you can see

[image]

Is there a way to get the same type of output as the first image but in a function ?

Comment: Use display from IPython instead of print -  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56385466/10276092

Comment: @M.Viking are you sure this works for R Jupyter Notebooks ? I tried `display(head(CO2))` and got `Error in display(head(CO2)): could not find function "display"`. Is it from a library ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jupyter display functions for IRkernel are provided by the [IRdisplay](https://github.com/IRkernel/IRdisplay) package, which gets installed together with IRkernel (by default). Just use:

```
IRdisplay::display(CO2)
```

Or load the library into the namespace first:

```
library(IRdisplay)
data("CO2")
a <- function() {
    display(head(CO2))
}
a()
```

Which works as intended:

[image]